# How to setup Tomcat 6 with Lighttpd so that Tomcat6 forwards requests to Lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd, tomcat6, configuration

I have run into this scenario where I have a Rackspace VPS server running Ubuntu 10.10 with Tomcat 6 serving a moderately complex JAVA WebApp using a fixed domain. The problem is that I would like to better utilize this setup and use Lighttpd to serve requests to other domains through Lighttpd. The issue is that *I would like to have Tomcat 6 face all the requests and handle requests to its own domain only while forwarding all others to Lighttpd*.

I have seen the reverse setup with Lighttpd handling requests and forwarding only specific requests to Tomcat 6 however, I would like to leave Tomcat 6's setup as is other than let it forward requests to domains it isn't serving to Lighttpd.

Is this possible?

Comment: I am not sure you can do that. I think it will be better to receive the requests by another web server: lighttpd or apache, and then forward some requests to tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `mod_proxy`

Maybe this article from 2007 will help:
http://rackerhacker.com/2007/04/05/lighttpd-proxy-to-tomcat/

I would say however that you would need lighttpd in front of tomcat. The other way around would be more of a hassle ... I would never put tomcat as the entry web server, it is just not suited for that, in my opinion.

Comment: I think I will be going with this approach as setting up Lighttpd to proxy is way more easier than Tomcat.